# How to list tabs within a screen session from command line while detatched

Tags: gnu-screen

I am trying to figure out a way to list all of the tabs in a specific screen session from command line.  Specifically, I just want to figure out if a tab exists of some particular name.

I have a script which creates a new tab in a session and runs a script there for a list of tab names.  For some reason, there are occasionally one or two tabs that don't get created and this throws off the top level script.  I want to add an acknowledgement in my top level script that checks if the particular tab was created and, if not, have a log that tells me this when I go back and look at the data.

Here is my top level code snippet, in case you may have any pointers on why a particular tab would not get created.  My guess is that the tabs get created too quickly and this potentially causes an error.  There are definitely no name conflicts

```
for f in $PWD/*; do
  if [ -d $f ]; then
    CMD="cd $f; bash cmd"

    # Creates a new screen window with title '$f' in existing screen session
    screen -S $SESSION_NAME -X screen -t $f

    # Switch terminal to bash
    screen -S $SESSION_NAME -p $f -X stuff "bash$(printf \\r)"

    # Launch $CMD in newly created screen window
    screen -S $SESSION_NAME -p $f -X stuff "$CMD$(printf \\r)"

  fi
done
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-Q` parameter with the command `windows`

> `-Q`   Some commands now can be queried from a remote session using this flag, e.g. "`screen -Q windows`". The commands will send the response to  the
>               stdout of the querying process. If there was an error in the command, then the querying process will exit with a non-zero status.